# DGSL (Directed Graph Shader Language) editor in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: hlsl, maya

I'm using the DGSL (Directed Graph Shader Language) editor in VS 2012 to create shader that I wish to export to HLSL and then load in MAYA

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh315733.aspx

At this stage I cannot for the life of me figure out to create custom naming for inputs and also expose variables so I can make connections in maya..

There is little or no documentation on this feature of VS..  has anyone had any experience with this editor to create shaders for programs like maya or max?